# What is the used and package of next command line \addtocontents{toc}{\vspace{2em}}?

Tags: packages, overleaf, thesis, paper, keycommand

Supposed me that line command is to Add a gap in the Contents, for aesthetics but also am search the line command that realize the blank page in my document so think that these the line command that produced the blank command. I not sure please help me.

Good Day¡¡¡¡

Comment: You're right, that inserts some vertical space of 2em size in your ToC (and 2em isn't that much, roughly the width of two uppercase M, depending on the font metrics of the current font).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se! Your question right now is quite hard to understand. You are correct that the `\addtocontents` is simply adding some vertical space between elements in the table of contents. It's not part of any package. Can you edit your question to show a small, compilable document that shows the problem you're having?

Comment: @Skillmon so thanks.

Comment: @AlanMunn is very large not like to share so much tex for these time.

Comment: @rotat We're not asking you to share your whole document (and in fact you should never do that). But we can't really help you unless you can construct a small sample document that reproduces the problem you're having. See [I've just been asked to write a minimal working example (MWE), what is that?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)